# How can I open new link in same window

Tags: watin

I have this html:

```
<a href="javascript:" />
```

Everytime, I do link.Click(), the page opens up a dialog window. I want it to open in this same page, and not in a dialog window. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: What happens when you view the page and click the link manually?

Answer (score 0):

The target tag will help you do this. Below sample will open the page in same page.

```
   <a target="_self" href="javascript:" />
```

For more details please refer to this link http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp